# Connect to remote minikube cluster using kubectl

Tags: docker, kubernetes, remote-access, minikube

I am looking to see if I can connect to a remote minikube cluster (Ubuntu box) using local (Mac) kubectl.  I currently use Docker and can do this very easily using `docker-machine`.  Simply eval to the machine name, and docker will use the remote machine.

I was wondering if there was anything similar for minikube/kubectl?  I have found a few articles that mention that I need to copy my remote `~/.minikube` directory to my local, and change some config about.  But this seems rather complicated for something a tool like `docker-machine` does seamlessly.

Is there a similar tool available, or if not, could someone help me with steps needed to connect to a remote cluster?

**Remote Machine**
Currently I use the `docker` driver (this is the complete output of the command, just the one line):

```
$ minikube config view
- driver: docker
```

And have a number of `NodePort` services:

```
$ kubectl get service -A
NAMESPACE     NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       apigateway        NodePort    10.100.122.255   <none>        8080:30601/TCP           19h
default       discoveryserver   NodePort    10.101.106.231   <none>        8761:30602/TCP           19h
default       elasticsearch     NodePort    10.97.197.14     <none>        9200:30604/TCP           19h
default       harness           NodePort    10.97.233.245    <none>        9090:30603/TCP           19h
default       kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  19h
default       mongo             NodePort    10.97.172.108    <none>        27017:32625/TCP          19h
kube-system   kube-dns          ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   19h
```

```
$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/meanwhileinhell/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.50.2:8443   <<<<<< `minikube ip`
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/meanwhileinhell/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /home/meanwhileinhell/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key
```

**Local machine**

```
$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
  name: docker-desktop
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /Users/mih.mac/remote/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.1.5:8443   <<<<<< Static IP of my remote machine
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-desktop
    user: docker-desktop
  name: docker-desktop
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: docker-desktop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: docker-desktop
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /Users/mih.mac/remote/.minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /Users/mih.mac/remote/.minikube/client.key
```

Comment: So, You are trying to run minikube cluster with docker driver on docker-machine and access it from the host?

Comment: No, not using docker-machine.  I was just mentioning it as for a standalone Docker environment, docker-machine makes this task very simple.  I was hoping that there would be a similar tool for accessing a K8s/minikube cluster remotely.

Comment: Did you manage to find solution ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no tool available. Way to remotely access minikube is to do SSH tunneling .

1- You need to be able to SSH from the Mac to the Ubuntu box.

2- Add appropriate SSH port forwarding flags.Run the following command

```
ssh -N -p 22 <user>@<public_ip> -L 127.0.0.1:18443:<minikube_ip>:8443
```

Where:

user is your name

public_ip is the public IP of your server

minikube_ip is the IP address of minikube, you can find it on the server using the command minikube ip. It will likely be 192.168.49.2.

3- Then just plug appropriate K8s credentials into kubectl on the Mac.

Please refer to the link for more information:

https://www.zepworks.com/posts/access-minikube-remotely-kvm/
https://www.chevdor.com/post/2021/02/docker_to_k8s/

Comment: This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Steps to connect to a remote minikube cluster from kubectl:

1. create a minikube cluster listening on a public interface, add a remote hostname and/or IP addresses to a generated certificate
   `minikube start --listen-address=0.0.0.0 --apiserver-names=example.com --apiserver-ips=1.2.3.4`
2. use `docker ps` to obtain a public port for the API server - it should proxy to an 8443 port inside minikube container (it will look like `0.0.0.0:32774->8443/tcp` - the port is 32774)
3. get kube config for minikube using `minikube kubectl -- config view` and save it to a local file (for example `~/minikube.config`)
4. edit `clusters[0].cluster.server` field in the `~/minikube.config` - set it to the appropriate remote host and port obtained in step 2
5. create a local directory for certificates and a key: `mkdir -p ~/.minikube/profiles/minikube`
6. copy `client.key`, `client.crt` and `ca.crt` from the minikube host to a local host:
   `scp 'example.com:.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.*' ~/.minikube/profiles/minikube/` and `scp 'example.com:.minikube/ca.crt' ~/.minikube/`
7. run locally `kubectl --kubeconfig ~/minikube.config get pod -A` to verify that it works

Answer (score 1):

You can use socat to forward minikube default IP and port (192.168.49.2:8443) to system default network card IP.

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8443,fork TCP4:192.168.49.2:8443
```